# Find $f^{(n)}(3)$ from the equation $\frac{(-1)^n(2)^nn!}{(3+2x)^{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Given $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{3+2x}$ and $a = 3$, find $f'(x)$, $f''(x)$, $f'''(x)$, $f''''(x)$, then for general $n$.

a. Find the formula for $f^{(n)}(x)$ and simplify.

b. Find $f^{(n)}(3)$ and simplify.

c. Find the Taylor coefficient $\displaystyle C_n = \frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(3)$ and simplify.

I got part a correct but apparently parts b and c are incorrect? Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: In b, what is $3+2x$ when $x=3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your working is the following step
$$f^{(n)}(3)=\frac{(-1)^n 2^n n!}{(3+2(3))^{n+1}}=\frac{(-1)^n 2^n n!}{2^{n+1}3^{n+1}}$$
You have distributed the exponent however forgot the 3+ existed. The correct way of doing it is
$$f^{(n)}(3)=\frac{(-1)^n 2^n n!}{(3+2(3))^{n+1}}=\frac{(-1)^n 2^n n!}{9^{n+1}}=\frac{(-1)^n 2^n n!}{3^{2n+2}}$$
From here you will calculate the correct Taylor coefficient as well.

Answer (score 1):

With $x=3$, you have $3+2x = 9 \neq 6$.